# How to use double-click instead click of expander?

Tags: wpf, expander

I have a `Expander` in `DataGrid`.

I want to instead click behavior, but it need to know IsSelected itself.

Then, use double-click expand.

I need a method easily to implement.

Have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to double-click to expand/collapse the `Expander`, you could handle its `Loaded` event, get a reference to the `ToggleButton` header button and then handle its `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` like this:

```
private void Expander_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Expander expander = sender as Expander;
    ToggleButton tb = FindVisualChild<ToggleButton>(expander);
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            ee.Handled = ee.ClickCount < 2;
        };
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Expander Header="Expand/Collapse..." Loaded="Expander_Loaded">
    <TextBlock>some content...</TextBlock>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Very thx, Your answer is pretty.But I have a issue, I still need one click to set it 'IsSelected', if I use this way, can do this issue?

Comment: I try to add code in `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` about expander' selected, then it's work.